# How can I provide adequate power to my 120V welder?

Tags: electrical, welding, 120v

I have a 120V welder (Harbor Freight Titanium 125) which has a rated input amps as high as 23.5A. However, it comes with a 15A plug. I have tripped the breaker a few times trying to run it near limits. I can make shorter beads and get around that but would like to be able to "send it" without dealing with that.

It seems like this is a common issue with 120V welders.

I was thinking about adding a 30A circuit and running it from that but it seems like overkill to run a tool I use infrequently. I have a 240V stick welder for when I want to really make sparks fly.

Any ways you've dealt with getting full performance out of a 120V welder while staying within code?

I do have a 20A circuit in my laundry which is adjacent to the garage. I see two plugs on it thus far. It seems that I could put another outlet on that circuit and flip it around into the garage (same wall) and have the amps I want. The other suggested 14-50 looks compelling too - I see an adapter on Amazon which will take a 14-50 and give you 4 outlets (2 pairs out of each phase).

Comment: Not entirely sure that this falls within the purview of [diy.se]. Yes, you can weld things to improve your home, but how to use the tool, which _could_ potentially be considered an appliance, would be off-topic. Not voting to close, but conflicted...

Comment: Is your 15A receptacle fed by a 15 or 20A circuit?

Comment: I don't understand what you would do with a 14-50 adapter here.   What are you adapting to what?  I think KMJ's answer is most practical.  Just find and use any existing outlet on a 20A breaker.

Answer (score 7):

So far as I can tell, most 120V welders take advantage of the fact that duty cycles for high current welding can be useful while being quite short. The closest you can get to a code-compliant solution for this problem is to make sure you're using it on a 20A circuit, even if it's a 15A outlet. Then you will at least pop the breaker less often. I solved my particular version of this problem by installing a 6-50 welder outlet, since my welder is dual-voltage.

Comment: The vision for this thing must have been "don't make them get an electrician".  So a 15A socket on a 20A circuit, which is VERY common, makes design sense.  I agree with the answer: Just find one of those!

Answer (score 5):

Your easiest option at this point is probably to try to find a 15 or 15/20A receptacle on an existing 20A circuit.

Just upsizing the breaker on the existing circuit is likely not acceptable because 15A circuits normally use #14awg NM (Romex) which is limited to 15A.

It is theoretically possible that you could inspect the whole circuit and find that #12 (or larger) wire was used exclusively, and somebody used the wrong size breaker, but I have always that to be a fools errand.

Running a new 20A circuit with #12 wire is really your best option for the welder you have, I'm a little surprised that UL/ETL/CSA doesn't call out for the instructions to specify a dedicated circuit.

Whatever your final determination is putting a 15 or 15/20A receptacle on a 30A circuit is expressively prohibited by [NEC 210.21(B)(1) or (3)](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.21_(B)).

You may (or may not) find it interesting to look at a [circuit breaker time curve](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219141/amperage-receptacles-breakers/219142#219142) to understand more clearly why a 20A breaker is probably adequate for a 23A load.

Comment: *I'm a little surprised that UL/ETL/CSA doesn't call out for the instructions to specify a dedicated circuit* I'm not at all surprised. A small welder is probably an "occasional" tool in a workshop for most people. A large welder (e.g., 240V 30A or larger circuit required) is a different story. Requiring a dedicated circuit would either hurt sales significantly (not UL's problem, but manufacturers will want to avoid getting in that situation) or simply be ignored. Requiring a 20A circuit by way of using a 20A plug would be reasonable, but apparently not required in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have 240 V power, you might be able to get a simple adapter from a NEMA 14-50 (50 A, 240 V oven outlet) or 14-30 (30 A, 240 V dryer outlet) to the plug on your welder. Though you'll probably have difficultly finding an adapter both rated for 30 A and with a 15 A or 20 A receptacle so you might have to replace the plug on your welder with a proper 30 A one (NEMA 5-30).

More than likely though the outlet for your 240 V welder isn't a dryer plug or oven plug but a NEMA 6-50 (50 A, 240 V, three prongs instead of four). In that case you'd need to replace that outlet with a 14-50 receptacle (or locking equivalent) and run your 240 V welder though an adapter. To replace the outlet you'd need to add a neutral wire, though there's a decent chance there's already one sitting in the box unused.

Comment: The dual-volt welders I have seen that are not Aliexpress-grade come with a 6-50 plug and then a 6-50 to 5-15 adapter. I think that's the safer way to go.

Comment: @KMJ You mean the adapter lets you plug the welder into a 5-15 receptacle? Because that just recreates the question asker's problem.

Comment: You're correct there. It doesn't solve the asker's problem. I'm just pointing it out as the usual way things work, for obvious safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I provide adequate power to my 120V welder?
>
> *I was thinking about adding a 30A circuit and running it from that but it seems like overkill to run a tool I use infrequently.*

this  ->  https://www.harborfreight.com/generators-engines/generators.html